# How to convert std::function to function pointer?

Tags: c++

I need to use `std::qsort()` to sort an arry of nd-Point. But I get an error:

> no known conversion from 'function<int (const void *, const void *)>' to '__compar_fn_t' (aka 'int (*)(const void *, const void *)')`

How to solve it, or sort it by dir in another method?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int d, n;
struct Point {
    int *x;
    Point() : x(new int[d]) {};
};

std::function<int(const void *, const void *)> make_cmp(int dir) {
    return [dir](const void *a, const void *b)->int {
        auto a_ = (Point *)a;
        auto b_ = (Point *)b;
        return a_->x[dir] - b_->x[dir];
    };
}

void sort_points(Point *value, int length, int dir) {
    std::qsort(value, length, sizeof(Point), make_cmp(dir));
}
```

Comment: Why not `std::sort` with a lambda?

Comment: C's `qsort` is not equipped to handle stateful comparison functions, and anyway it's terribly unsafe. More generally, things that are good practice in C are often terrible practice in C++, and this code displays several of them. Raw new[] instead of `std::vector`, `qsort` instead of `std::sort`, just hoping that the flat memcopy `qsort` does won't break the C++ type system...it's not impossible to write code this way that works, if you're extremely careful and knowledgeable about language rules, but it's needlessly difficult, error-prone and hard to maintain. Why do it this way?

Comment: Because `std::sort` and stl is nor permitted in the oj of my data strucutre course. I don't know why...

Comment: @zhaozk you are using `std::function` (which is part of the standard library) and lambdas, but are not allowed to use `std::sort()`? That makes no sense, it is a stupid limitation that teaches you nothing useful. You need to talk to your teacher. You can't use `std::function` with `std::qsort()`, they are simply not compatible. Neither is a *capturing* lambda, for that matter. A *non-capturing* lambda  is compatible with `std::qsort()` but that doesn't solve your task. `qsort_s()` (no `std::`) would solve your task, though.

Comment: It annoys me to no end when people teach "C++" this way. It's like they're stuck in 1985 and have never written a line of actual production code. C-with-classes was good enough for my grandfather, it's good enough for me, that kind of vibe. These guys have no business attempting to teach anyone. Bloody hell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you must use `std::qsort` then you are basically writing in C, not C++.  This might be one of the few situations where a global variable is the least bad approach.

```
static thread_local int dir;

int cmp(const void *a, const void *b) {
    auto a_ = (const Point *)a;
    auto b_ = (const Point *)b;
    return a_->x[dir] - b_->x[dir]; // beware of overflow
}

void sort_points(Point *value, int length, int d) {
    dir = d;
    std::qsort(value, length, sizeof(Point), cmp);
}
```

If this will never be called from more than one thread at a time, then you can drop the `thread_local`.

(Note that if the values might exceed the range `[INT_MIN/2, INT_MAX/2]` then you need to replace the subtraction with something that isn't vulnerable to overflow.)